# Monodevelop and mongodb driver throws exception in development server on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, mongodb, ubuntu, monodevelop, appharbor

The following code runs fine on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/).

```
public virtual void button1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

            button1.Text = "You clicked me";
            MongoServer ms=MongoServer.Create("mongodb://sbose78:xxxxx@staff.mongohq.com:10068/BOSE");
            MongoDatabase db= ms.GetDatabase("BOSE");
            MongoCollection<User> users=db.GetCollection<User>("users");
            button1.Text=users.Count().ToString();


        }
```

However it runs into an exception on my Ubuntu box.
I'm using Monodevelop.

```
Server Error in '/' Application
recursionPolicy != NoRecursion not currently implemented

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.NotImplementedException: recursionPolicy != NoRecursion not currently implemented
  at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim..ctor (LockRecursionPolicy recursionPolicy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.6.7 (Debian 2.6.7-3ubuntu1); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

What could possibly be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a version of MonoDevelop (Mono actually) that is too old.

We test against:

MonoDevelop 2.8.2
Mono 2.10.1

Comment: Could you point me to the exact download link for MonoDevelop 2.8.2. what is the difference between Mono and MonoDevelop?

Comment: MonoDevelop is an integrated development environment (text editor, compiler, debugger). Mono is the runtime and libraries that emulate .NET.

Comment: I see that there slightly newer versions of MonoDevelop and Mono than we are using. Anything newer than what we test against should be fine.

Comment: I'm using the highest version of MonoDevelop that's available for ubuntu. Also, this doesn't have a GUI designer :(

Comment: Ubuntu 12 has Mono 2.10.8.1, can't you install that?